# Creating an issue using JIRA Rest API returns HTTP status code 200 but the issue is not created

Tags: c#, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to create an issue with Jira Rest API using C#

```
            string data = @"{ ""fields"": { 
                                ""project"":
                   {
                       ""key"": ""TOTEM""
                   },
                                ""summary"": ""just a test"",
                                ""description"": ""Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API"",
                                ""issuetype"": {
                                    ""name"": ""Task""
                                },
                                ""assignee"": { ""name"": ""imane.elbarchi"" }
                            }
            }";

            //Console.WriteLine(data);

            string uri = "https://proactioneu.ent.cgi.com/rest/api/latest/issue";

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            //Putting URI in client base address.
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

            //Putting the credentials as bytes.
            byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");

            //Putting credentials in Authorization headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));

            //Putting content-type into the Header.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //I am using StringContent because I am creating console application, no any serialize I used for manipulate the string.
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and I get a response like:

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'Found', Version: 1.0, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
>       {
>         Cache-Control: no-cache
>         Connection: close
>         Content-Type: text/html
>       }

but the issue is not created.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of this line:

```
   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;
```

When I create an issue I use:

```
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, content);
```

So the first parameter wants the url you want to send the content to. "issue" is not an url.

My code looks like this. Maybe you can use it.

```
        public async Task<bool> PostIssueAsync(string userpass, string data)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.JiraUrl + "rest/api/latest/issue");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", userpass);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, content);
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```